# Java - Trying to create circle objects inside array

Tags: java

I'm trying to use an array to help me generate a new circle object in a new spot of the array each time I click a button. This is the error I am receiving:

> Bean_Drop.java:179: error: array required, but Circle found
>
> currentBall[n] = new Circle(shift, yRed[n], RADIUS);

code:

trying to create array:

```
private Circle[] currentBall = new Circle[NUMBER_OF_SLOTS];
```

Trying to implement in method:

```
public void dropABall() {
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
    r = rand.nextInt((55) + 1) + 100;
    g = rand.nextInt((55) + 1) + 100;
    b = rand.nextInt((55) + 1) + 100;
    shift = paneWidth / 2;
    moveCount[n] = 0;
    position[n] = 0;
    yRed[n] = RED_BALL_START_Y;
    currentBall[n] = new Circle(shift, yRed[n], RADIUS);
    currentBall[n].setFill(Color.rgb(r,g,b,1.0));
    getChildren().add(currentBall);

}
```

I am doing this because I have n increase each time I click a button, so I want it to place a circle in that position of the array.

Comment: what is 'n' ? can u add the code that calls the dropABall function ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/dJzJWgjP line 243

Comment: For future questions, please try to pare your question down to a _minimal_ example that (a) shows the error and (b) doesn't show anything else. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that method is inside BeanMachine, which defines a *different* variable, `private Circle currentBall` (line 109 in your pastebin link). What the error message says is that when it saw `currentBall[n]`, it expected `currentBall` to be an array, but it found that it's actually a Circle.

This is why it's dangerous to define two methods with the same name (which is called "shadowing") -- it can be confusing to humans.

Answer (score 0):

The currentBall is of type Circle in the BeanMachine
but its a Circle array Circle[] in the Bean_Drop.

so when you call it from those different classes you will have a different behaviour. 
i guess change the name to currentBalls (plural) on the Bean_Drop class will be more expressive and less error pruned.